# Difficulty in opening database in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

I am having difficulty opening my database in my class. I am trying to get my application to start on the phone bootup, that is only if the boolean value in the database is true, if false it will not boot the application on startup. I have the errors to the bottom

```
public class My_BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
private static String DBNAME2 = "database2.db";
private static String Table2 = "options";

Boolean isOk = true;
Context context;

@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    try {

        sqlDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME2, null);

        Cursor r = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT Apponstart FROM " + Table2, null);
        System.out.println("COUNT of Location: " + r.getCount());
        int loc = r.getColumnIndex("Apponstart");

        int j = 0;
        if (r.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Apponstart is " + r.getString(loc));

                isOk = Boolean.parseBoolean(r.getString(loc));

                j++;
            } while (r.moveToNext());
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.println("No data found");
            }

        }
        r.close();
        // sqlDB.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sqlDB.close();
    }

    if(isOk){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, JoshTwoActivity.class);                   
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                
        context.startActivity(i); 
    }
}



 09-23 08:10:05.615: WARN/System.err(208): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
        09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
        09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
        09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
        09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
        09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at three.three.My_BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(My_BroadcastReceiver.java:31)
         09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
         09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
           09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
          09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
          09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
          09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
         09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
         09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
         09-23 08:10:05.625: WARN/System.err(208):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And again at

```
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start receiver three.three.My_BroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at three.three.My_BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(My_BroadcastReceiver.java:57)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
       09-23 08:10:06.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(208):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Why don't u use logging and/or a debugger to find the problem? You get any logmessage (even those from boottime) in `adb logcat`, so where is your problem narrowing down the problem? BTW: `System.out` is not the desired way to log on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database was the problem. I created a method and added context to the opening of the database. Here is my solution.

```
public void guru(Context ctx){

    System.out.println("Flax");
    try {
        Log.e("troll", "alol");
        sqlDB = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME2, 0,null); 
        //sqlDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME2, null);           
        Cursor r = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT Apponstart FROM " + Table2, null);
        System.out.println("COUNT of Location: " + r.getCount());
        int loc = r.getColumnIndex("Apponstart");

        int j = 0;
        if (r.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Apponstart is " + r.getString(loc));
                Log.d("happening", "here");
                isOk = Boolean.parseBoolean(r.getString(loc));

                j++;
            } while (r.moveToNext());
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.println("No data found");
            }

        }
        r.close();
        // sqlDB.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        sqlDB.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will probably need more code to solve the problem, but I imagine the problem has something to do with teh way that the receiver is registered. Do you declare in XML or via registerReceiver? Is this onReceive ever being reached?

Read about the BroadcastReceiver lifecycle on this reference page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I register the reciever in my Manifest.xml. OnReceive works, when I take the database code out. If I leave the simple startActivity it works fine